Aggregating to json format - Trino / Hive
I use Trino and Hive in Jupyter Notebook. I want to aggregate a table in the following way:
q = f"""
CREATE TABLE {aggregated_table} AS
WITH aggregated_data AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        date,
        -- Aggregate counts into JSON strings
        json_format(
            map_agg(column_A, COUNT(column_A))
        ) AS column_A_counts,
        AVG(column_B) AS column_B_avg,
        FIRST_VALUE(column_C) OVER (PARTITION BY id, date) AS column_C
    FROM
        {disaggregated_table}
    GROUP BY
        id, date
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    aggregated_data
"""

%sql $q

The error that I get is:
TrinoUserError(type=USER_ERROR, name=FUNCTION_NOT_FOUND, message="line ...: Unexpected parameters (map(varchar(5),bigint)) for function json_format. Expected: json_format(json)"
How should I solve it?

json_format requires JSON data type, you can cast to it, for example:
cast(map_agg(column_A, COUNT(column_A)) as JSON)

